# Setting Up Recurrence

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, recurrence, floor

I have a question where I'm completely confused how to set up a recurrence.

A watch manufacturer looks to find out if an integer value for water resistance is in the range of 0 to n. The water resistance is 0 if a watch leaks, and the watch does not leak at the depth of n meters. The water resistance is defined as n.

To test the water resistance at a depth k, a scuba diver does a dive at k meters and stays
under water at that depth for one hour. If the watch leaks, it is discarded. If it does not
leak, it can be reused in another experiment.

**How many watches leak in the worst case? (worst case here means the
maximum number of damaged watches)?**

What's given: Describe the worst case situation and then give a recurrence relation for the number of damaged watches. Assume that the midpoint is chosen for the sub-problem for row lower to upper by the formula: `mid = floor[(lower+upper)/2] where lower = 1, and upper = n` 
for the first sub-problem.

So what I got from this is `mid = floor[(1+n)/2]` 
but I'm not sure how to come up with a recurrence that holds for any value of n.

Can someone guide me on what to do / how to get started? I would appreciate any help from anyone.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you give an example?

Comment: The question is asking how many watches leak in the worst case (meaning to set up a recurrence equation for it.)

I edited my original post, I hope you can help me. Thanks for response Abhishek.

Comment: It'll be helpful if you can provide a sample input and output data.

Comment: I do not have any sample input / output data as this is just based on the recurrence. That is why I am asking for help because I don't know how to set it up. All that is given is the midpoint (which is between lower and upper).

Comment: I've edited the original post to add any missing parts.

Comment: Sounds very similar to [Throwing cats out of windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974077/throwing-cats-out-of-windows).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to minimize the total number of watches leaked, then it is one. You can just test it sequentially for k = 0, k = 1, etc till a watch leaks. The complexity for number of tests in this case is O(m) where m is the water resistance of the watches.

If you want to minimize the total number of tests, then IMO it is a binary search problem. You are searching for the minimum k at which the watches leak.

Start from the mid-point.

If the watch leaks, then its resistance is less than the mid-point.

```
Hence new mid-point = (lower + mid-point)/2.
```

If it does not leak, then its resistance is greater than the mid-point.

```
Hence new mid-point = (mid-point + upper)/2.
```

In the worst case, all the tested watches leak. This is the complexity of the algorithm which is `O(logn)`.

If you have a constraint on the maximum number of watches you can leak or the maximum number of trials you can do, then you should follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974077/throwing-cats-out-of-windows) shown by @Dukeling  for suitable Dynamic Programming formulation.

Comment: As hinted by article pointed by @Dukeling, the optimal should be found using dynamic programming, and not binary search. =)

Comment: @justhalf OOPs! mis-interpreted the question. Shall delete my answer.

Comment: @justhalf See my update. IMO This problem is slightly different from the linked question because, there is no constraint on the maximum number of watches.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses. I was trying to find how to set up the recurrence though for T(n) using the floor and ceiling function as I included for the given midpoint sub-problem. Hope someone can respond again, thanks for all the resourceful comments.

Comment: Can anyone provide any assistance?

Comment: @user2958631 I suggest you look up the link that Dukeling provided. That explains clearly how to approach such problems and how to set up the recurrence relation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974077/throwing-cats-out-of-windows

Comment: I have looked at it but I don't see the relation between the questions. I'm mainly wondering how to get the recurrence from just the midpoint